# Efficient file upload in SQL Server using MVC Application

Tags: sql-server, sqlfilestream

i have a scenario of uploading multiple files from asp.net mvc form.
Which one would be more efficient:
Saving files in to sql server with blob column (and using filestream) or saving files in application's upload directory and maintaining the filepath in db column.
In short SQLserver blob storage vs directory upload

Comment: By efficient do you mean coding time or upload time or system maintenance time? Do you need to do anything with the files once you've uploaded them? i.e. display them again? Search them? Show them in a grid mixed in with other database data? Basically do you need to associate these files with database records?

Comment: Also, consider *consistency* - is that a desired quality of your system? If a stored path refers to a file that no longer exists, is that a problem?